# Can't get url Parameter inside controllerFunction node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

In my index.js I have given routing in such a manner.

```
app.use('/users/:id/transactions',transactionRoutes)
```

Inside transactionRoutes

```
router.get('/:txnHash',transactionController.getTransaction);
```

so request to '/users/:id/transactions/:txnHash' will come to the above route.

Inside transactionController

```
module.exports.getTransaction = (req,res) => {
    let typeOfTransaction = req.query.type,
        userId            = req.params.id,
        txnHash           = req.params.txnHash;
}
```

**Here I am able to access the txnHash parameter but the userId parameter shows undefined**. I think it is because the :id part of the route is specified in the index.js. Is there any method to solve this problem without changing the routes.

API Request is

**GET 'apiurl/users/42342234/transactions/234bh2428b354hjcs'**

Comment: Can you provide sent request

Comment: Try `req.param('id')` and see if it works.

Comment: @GobuCSG please check the new edit.

Comment: @DavidR tried, but it shows the message given below                                 
express deprecated req.param(name): Use req.params, req.body, or req.query instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `TransactionRoutes` you need to add `mergeParams` which will preserve the `req.params` values.

```
var router = express.Router({mergeParams: true});
```

Before your,

```
router.get('/:txnHash',transactionController.getTransaction);
```

Hope this helps!